# How to use "wget" to save a file as a different name

Tags: unix, wget

wget "http://flakejfl2ke3jrlwkefj38j2ofiwejfoifjalsdkfje3fklwje.exe" is long.

How do I save it as my own name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
wget http://longname -O short_name
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't retain the default behavior of renaming conflicts

Answer (score 8):

In the spirit of teaching a man to fish:

```
man wget
```

Comment: amen...or just google wget

Comment: .... which brings me to this page.

Answer (score 5):

Use the -O option:

```
wget -O myfile.html http://www.google.com/
```